# MYSQL AS keyword error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use AS in my MYSQL query below:

```
select ddb.customer_id, ddb.eta,ddb.vessel from tb_po
where transport_mode='SEA'  
and date(mv_eta_pod) between '2010-01-01' and  '2020-12-31' AS ddb;
```

However, it tells me I am having an error in the `AS` keyword. Is there something wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: +1 for providing code and concrete error description. You can use inline code formatting by enclosing into backticks, e.g. ` `AS` `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AS` to define alias for the table you use i.e. `tb_po`.

```
select ddb.customer_id, ddb.eta,ddb.vessel from tb_po AS ddb
where transport_mode='SEA'  
and date(mv_eta_pod) between '2010-01-01' and  '2020-12-31';
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put AS directly after the thing you want to create an alias for (ex. a table or a specific row).